# How do I fix this error (unable to find resource t32.exe) that I get when I try to upgrade pip on Windows 10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 186, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 395, in run
    installed = install_given_reqs(
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\__init__.py", line 67, in install_given_reqs
    requirement.install(
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 809, in install
    install_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 607, in install_wheel
    install_unpacked_wheel(
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 548, in install_unpacked_wheel
    generated_console_scripts = maker.make_multiple(scripts_to_generate)
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 415, in make_multiple
    filenames.extend(self.make(specification, options))
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\install\wheel.py", line 280, in make
    return super(PipScriptMaker, self).make(specification, options)
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 404, in make
    self._make_script(entry, filenames, options=options)
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 304, in _make_script
    self._write_script(scriptnames, shebang, script, filenames, ext)
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 239, in _write_script
    launcher = self._get_launcher('t')
  File "C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip\_vendor\distlib\scripts.py", line 383, in _get_launcher
    raise ValueError(msg)
ValueError: Unable to find resource t32.exe in package pip._vendor.distlib
```

Please take a look!

Comment: What is your command to update the pip?
Please provide the input which causes this errors.

Comment: My guess is he tried "python -m pip install --upgrade pip" or some variation of it.

Answer (score 7):

This one worked perfectly for me without any additional installations or 3rd party scripts:

```
python -m pip uninstall pip
python -m ensurepip
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

1. uninstall current pip:

   ```
   python -m pip uninstall pip setuptools
   ```
2. download `get-pip.py` from https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
3. execute get-pip script:

   ```
   python get-pip.py
   ```

   Don't forget to mark answer correct if you find it helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I visited this [page](https://www.pconlife.com/download/otherfile/26956/f848a48532cbc478c15234e75fc08e16/) and searched for the missing resource "**t32.exe**".
Scroll down the page and complete the capture, and click on download. [t32.exe file download.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aig04.png)

Before you download, make sure your antivirus is on to avoid any problems after the download.

After downloading, go to the directory

> C:\Users\CR1008tu\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pip_vendor\distlib\

Now copy and paste the downloaded **t32.exe** file and paste it into the directory and save it. Now run `python -m pip install -–upgrade pip` again.